# RVM: Tests and Rails start very, very slowly using Ruby 1.8.7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

I'm using RVM to manage my environments for a few Rails projects.  One of them is running Rails 3 on ruby 1.9.2, and one is running Rails 2.3 on ruby 1.8.7.  The 1.8.7 environment is *very* slow to start any rails-based tasks (console, server, tests) - I mean 45s - 2 minutes depending on what's happening.  The 1.9.2 environment is as snappy as can be.

I've tried playing with the patch level of the 1.8.7 environment, but that only helped a bit, and only for certain tasks (console and server).  Tests still take forever to start, even when I'm running them individually with a ruby command.

Does anyone have an idea of what could be happening here?

Comment: Weird. Commonly it is the other way around. In 1.9.2 there was a load-bug, which is now fixed in 1.9.3. Maybe try again in a clean gemset?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use spork gem which preload environment to your rails application. But it only depends on rspec tasks, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Another way: try to use ruby enterprise edition. http://www.rubyenterpriseedition.com/